# Xcode cannot locate localized info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info.plist

After adding a few Localizations:

[image]

and localized the `(AppName)-info.plist` file:

[image]

and checked Bundle Resources (also tried to remove Go-info.plist from the `Copy Resources Bundle` list:

[image]

and the file property:

[image]

Xcode (4.6.3) give an error:

> error: could not read data from '.../Go/Go/Go-Info.plist': The file
>   “Go-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

It looks like Xcode ignores the localization folder in the path. It tried to find the info.plist as:

```
.../Go/Go/Go-Info.plist
```

instead of:

```
.../Go/Go/(Localization)/Go-Info.plist
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can localize an info.plist. If you want to localize your AppName you should localize the infoPlist.strings file and add those keys : "CFBundleDisplayName" = "AppName";
"CFBundleName" = "AppName";

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think **Info.plist** can not be localized. If you want to localize your application Name, you should localize the **InfoPlist.strings** file and use those keys :

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "AppName";
"CFBundleName" = "AppName";
```

Comment: Drop the double quote of key as it's a NSString value already, works good for me.

Comment: Here's the Apple Doc for reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that Info.plist and InfoPlist.strings are 2 things... I think many "smart" people like me would overlook their difference when localizing.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step localized Info.plist:

1. Find in the x-code the folder Resources (is placed in root)
2. Select the folder Resources
3. Then press the main menu File->New->File...
4. Select in section "Resource" Strings File and press Next
5. Then in Save As field write InfoPlist ONLY ("I" capital and "P" capital)
6. Then press Create
7. Then select the file InfoPlist.strings that created in Resources folder and press in the right menu the button "Localize"
8. Then you Select the Project from the Project Navigator and select the The project from project list
9. In the info tab at the bottom you can as many as language you want (There is in section Localizations)
10. The language you can see in Resources Folder
11. To localize the values ("key") from info.plist file you can open with a text editor and get all the keys you want to localize
12. You write any key as the example in any InfoPlist.strings like the above example

"NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription"="blabla";

"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"="blabla2";

That's all work and you have localize your info.plist file!